# How to set the Azure Service Bus topic at publishing time with MassTransit?

Tags: azureservicebus, masstransit, azure-servicebus-topics

I'm trying to set the topic at publishing time, because I need to derive it from the message content.

I tried to work on the publishing context, like (in a `IPipe`):

```
public Task Send(PublishContext<MyMessageType> context)
{
    context.DestinationAddress = CalculateDestinationAddress(context);

    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

But didn't work. Also looked for other ways/points to override the topic but didn't find anything.

Anyone aware of how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to send to a topic of any given name, using the *topic* address syntax instead:

```cs
var endpoint = await sendEndpointProvider.GetSendEndpoint(new Uri("topic:name"));
await endpoint.Send(message);
```

`sendEndpointProvider` is available via the `ConsumeContext` when consuming a message, or via the `ISendEndpointProvider` interface from the container.